# Emscripten handover double array - Apparently random address is received

Tags: c++, arrays, typescript, webassembly, emscripten

I have trouble handing over a double array to a WASM file, that is generated via emscripten. I have generated it as a .js output file with WASM=1, so I also have a wasm file.

This is my abbreviated C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
  }

  double *calculate(double *x, double *y, int array_length) {
    std:cout << "Array Length: " << array_length << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
      std::cout << "Coords: " << x[i] << ", " << y[i] << endl;
    }
    return new double[7]{1,1,2,3,5,8,13};
  }
}
```

It produces this output in the browser console:

```
Array Length: 4 average.js:8:16057
Coords: 2.36377e+232, 2.36377e+232 average.js:8:16057
Coords: 5.9419e-310, 5.9419e-310 average.js:8:16057
Coords: 4.28375e-319, 4.28375e-319 average.js:8:16057
Coords: 1.4854e-313, 1.4854e-313
```

I can see it does something.

This is the code calling it:

```js
import { CalculationAdapterInterface, Coords, GraphData } from "../CalculationAdapterInterface";
import averageModule from "./average"

export default class CalculationWasmAdapter implements CalculationAdapterInterface {
  

  async calculate(data: GraphData): Promise<Coords|void> {
    
    const x = [ 5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0];
    const y = x.map(x => x/2);
    const to_byte = (arr: number[]) => { return new Float64Array(arr).buffer}

    const filePath = window.location.origin + "/average.wasm";
    averageModule({locateFile: () => filePath}).then((module: any) => {
      const calculate = module.cwrap('calculate', 'number', ['array', 'array', 'int'])
      calculate(to_byte(x), to_byte(y), x.length);
    })
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the output in the browser is generated.
When I change the input values in the array, it does not change the printed values (except for how many are printed). I strongly suspect that the c++ code does not receive the array and reads from some default allocated space. But why?

Comment: `double x[], double y[]` -- I don't know about the caller to the `C++` code, but please note that these are *not* arrays.  They are `double *`, thus the caller should be passing pointers to the data.

Comment: I changed it in c++, but that didn't change anything. Or do you mean the calling function? I thought that was what cwrap did? Or do you mean that I have to manually put it on the wasm heap?

Comment: I do not know wasm, but I am referring to the calling function.  In C++, this: `double *calculate(double *x, double *y, int array_length)` is *exactly* the same as this: `double *calculate(double x [], double y [], int array_length)`.  I have no idea what `cwrap` does, but regardless, whatever it does, it needs to pass the address of the first value in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only ever done this once and I don't claim to be the expert but I had success passing an array of doubles from JavaScript to C++ using this technique.

The way I understand it, if you want to [access memory from JavaScript](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#access-memory-from-javascript), you have to be aware that JavaScript and WebAssembly have different memory layouts. You use `HEAPF64.set` to copy data from a JavaScript array (with its own memory layout) to the Emscripten HEAP, where it can be accessed by the WebAssembly module.

Here's my example, which is node.js (sorry, that's how I was using it), but something similar should be possible in the browser platform.

```js
const factory = require('./src/passarray.js');
factory().then(instance => {
  const doubleArray = new Float64Array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]);

  const arrayPointer = instance._malloc(doubleArray.length * doubleArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
  instance.HEAPF64.set(doubleArray, arrayPointer / doubleArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);

  instance._exampleFunction(arrayPointer);

  instance._free(arrayPointer);
});
```

On the C++ side:

```cpp
extern "C" {
  EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
  void exampleFunction(double* elems) { 
    // [your code here]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you get stuck exporting _malloc and _free, don't forget to specify them as `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`  See https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/6882#issuecomment-406745898

Comment: This worked out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code clip that shows how to pass float arrays to and from C with tiny-wasm-runtime (disclaimer - which i wrote).  This is for 32bit float, but the same technique works for doubles (64 bit float).  The C function accepts an array of floats C style.

You can find the full example source (Javascript calling C FFT lib and graphing results) here:
https://github.com/twiddlingbits/tiny-wasm-runtime/tree/main/examples/fft

And the FFT example running live here:
https://twiddlingbits.dev/examples/dist/fft/index.html

```
import {twrWasmModule} from "tiny-wasm-runtime";
const mod=new twrWasmModule();

// load the kiss_fft C code as is, unmodified
await mod.loadWasm('kiss_fft.wasm');
//...
let inArrayBuf:ArrayBuffer;
let in:Float32Array;

inArrayBuf=new ArrayBuffer(SIZE);  
in=new Float32Array(inArrayBuf);
//...
await mod.callC(["kiss_fft", ..., inArrayBuf, outArrayBuf]);
//...
```